# Please help me understand the proof

Tags: logic

[image]

[image: Here is the proof]

**Doubt**

In third line of the proof, why is Q $\rightarrow$ R ?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The proof runs as follows :

1) $P$ --- assumed [a]

2) $\lnot R$ --- assumed [b]

3) $\lnot R \to (P \to \lnot Q)$ --- premise

4) $P \to \lnot Q$ --- from 2) and 3) by *modus ponens*

5) $\lnot Q$ --- from 1) and 4) by *modus ponens*

6) $\lnot R \to \lnot Q$ --- from 2) and 5) by *Deduction Th* (or [Conditional Proof](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conditional_proof)), discharging [b]

7) $Q \to R$ --- from 6) by [Contraposition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Contraposition)

> 8)  $P \to (Q \to R)$ --- from 1) and 7) by *Deduction Th* (or *Conditional Proof*), discharging [a].

Comment: @TaylorTed - I've inserted the link to Wiki's page for *Conditional Proof* : you have met it somewhere in your textbook or lecture notes, perhaps with some other name. The rule works assuming a "temporary" premise : $\lnot R$ and deriving a conclusion (in this case : $¬Q$) with the help of it. Thus, from the fact that the conclusion is licensed under the "temporary" premise : $\lnot R$, we apply the rule and conclude with the *conditional* : **if** $\lnot R$, **then** $\lnot Q$.

Answer (score 2):

Here's another way to think about it. Starting from the assumption:
$$\lnot R \rightarrow (P \rightarrow \lnot Q)$$
$$R \lor (P \rightarrow \lnot Q) $$
$$ R \lor (\lnot P \lor \lnot Q)$$
$$ (R \lor \lnot P) \lor (R \lor \lnot Q) $$
Now, assume $P$. We have two cases: $R\lor \lnot P$ or $R \lor \lnot Q$. If we assume the former, $R \lor \lnot P$, then because of $P$, we have
$$R$$
$$R \lor \lnot Q$$
$$\lnot Q \lor R$$
$$Q \rightarrow R$$
If we assume the latter, $R \lor \lnot Q$, then
$$\lnot Q \lor R$$
$$Q \rightarrow R $$
Thus in either case we have $Q \rightarrow R$. Therefore $P \rightarrow (Q \rightarrow R)$

Comment: "then because of P we have R ". Can you throw more light on this, i cannot understand this

Comment: Beacse it is R V $\neg$ P and not R V P

Answer (score -1):

$ \neg R \implies \neg Q \Leftrightarrow Q \implies R$

Comment: There's a chance that this answers OP's problem; there's also a chance that it **is** OP's problem.  (Also, you probably meant the TeX macro "backslash neg", which produces things like $\neg R$, rather than "backslash not", which produces things like $\not R$.)